# For loops to make a bar graph in C# console

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, console

I am trying to make a function that takes in two values: an array **scores[]** and an int **elmts**.
The goal is for the function to print a line of * stars for each value in the **scores[]** array.
For example, if we had

```
int[] scores = {5, 1, 10};
elmts = 3;
```

I would want it to print this to the console:

```
 * * * * *
 *
 * * * * * * * * * *
```

I've tried to implement this with the two nested for loops below:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < elmts; i++)
    {
         for(int k = 0; k < scores[k]; k++)
         {
             Write(" *");
         }
         WriteLine();
    }
```

But the output is:

```
*
*
*
```

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong here?

Comment: Walk through your loop and pay attention to scores[k]: k= 0, scores[k] = 5; k = 1, scores[k] = 1

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you had the indexer wrong in your array, specifically `scores[k]` should seemingly be `scores[i]`

```
var scores = new[] {4, 3, 4, 6, 4};

for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
{
   for (int k = 0; k < scores[i]; k++)
      Console.Write(" *");
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Another way you could do this is

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
   Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(" *", scores[i])));
```

or

```
foreach (var score in scores)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(" *", score)));
```

or

```
var graph = scores.Select(x => string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(" *", x)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, graph));
```

**Output**

```
 * * * *
 * * *
 * * * *
 * * * * * *
 * * * *
```